# Access only basic details about the user from Google+ sdk - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, google-plus

I've successfully integrated google plus sdk in my ios app. Right now its getting all the info of the user but I don't want to access his friends or circles but only his full name, google+ id, email, location and stuffs like that.

Went through stackoverflow but couldn't find anything related to it. Sorry can't include images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scopes that you request, make sure to just specify the string, "profile", for example:

```
signIn.scopes = @[ @"profile" ]; // Only the "profile" scope
```

This will request the minimum amount of data from the user. However, you will not be able to get the user's email address. For the email address, you must request the "email" scope. For example:

```
signIn.scopes = @[ @"email" ]; // The Email scope
```

Comment: Is there any way to get user's location from google plus sdks or API?